# acro-package: Always use long form for defined acronym?

Tags: acronyms, acro

Is there a convenient switch to make `acro` always use the long form for selected acronyms?  I would like to be able to toggle that.  Otherwise, I have to search and replace acro commands with (say) `\acl`, `\aclp`, etc. (and I'd lose track of where all my `\acs`'s were).

AFTERNOTE: My current approach is to define the short form to be the same as the long form, then list the acronym under `\acuse` so that the first occurrence isn't treated specially.  The fatal drawback is that the acronym still shows up in the list of acronyms at the end of the document.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to tell your readers, that a specific term (ST) has an acronym (AN), but then, instead of using that AN, always write out the long form of that specific term. Is that right?

Comment: If you're happy to change package this can be done quite easily with `glossaries`. (The `shortcut` package option provides the synonyms `\ac`, `\acp`, `\acs`, `\acl` etc that are shared by `acro`, `acronym` and `glossaries` for much the same purposes.)

Comment: @thymaro: Temporarily, I don't want any indication that a short form is used at all.

Comment: @Nicola: I moved to acro package years ago, for various reasons that I don't recall, so I'd prefer to stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

All acronyms can be set to give their long form by setting `\acro_use:n` which check the acronyms used status and then picks long/short/first form accordingly to instead always fetch the long form with `\acro_long:n`

```
\cs_set_eq:NN \acro_use:n \acro_long:n
```

This won't affect calls for the short or alt forms, they will still appear as the short/alt forms as internally they use `\acro_short:n` and `\acro_alt:n` but these can also be set to call the `\acro_long:n` form if so desired.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \acro_use:n \acro_long:n
\cs_set_eq:NN \acro_short:n \acro_long:n
\cs_set_eq:NN \acro_alt:n \acro_long:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

should essentially turn off all `\ac`-type macros and make them expand to the long form only.

If looking to only disable it for a set of acronyms, say those identified with `class = maybelongonly` then one can modify the `\acro_use:n` to insert a check of the acronyms class and accordingly print it as normal (for [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro)) or print the long form only.  To check the class `\acro_get_property:nn` is used, which was introduced in v2.7

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{ecm}{
  short = ECM ,
  long  = Electro Chemical Machining,
  class = maybelongonly,
}
\DeclareAcronym{adc}{
  short = ADC ,
  long  = Analog-to-Digital-Converter
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__acro_longonly_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l__acro_longonly_tl { maybelongonly }

\cs_set_eq:NN \acro_useold:n \acro_use:n
\cs_set:Npn \acro_use:n #1 {
    \acro_get_property:nn { #1 } { class }
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l__acro_class_tl \l__acro_longonly_tl {
        \acro_long:n { #1 }
    }{
        \acro_useold:n { #1 }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ac{ecm}

\ac{ecm}

\acp{adc}

\Ac{ecm}

\acp{ecm}

\Iac{adc}
\end{document}
```

this will ensure `\acp{<key>}` prints always printsthe long version with the appropriate plural for acronyms in the appropriate class.  In order to catch any explicit calls for the short or alt versions (`\acs`, `\aca` etc.) then `\acro_short:n` and `\acro_alt:n` should be modified similarly to `\acro_use:n`.

These acronyms can be removed from the list by giving `\printacronyms` the key `exclude-classes=maybelongonly`.

Comment: Thanks, Dai.  I may give this a spin in any future need to temporarily undefine acronyms.  It's seems to be a bit more work than my (admittedly inelegant) solution.

Comment: @user36800 it depends, for this answer all you need to do is add some code which creates a switch to ignore the acronym according to a property and then set the class of any acronyms to be ignored to be whatever that switch is looking for (the value given in `\tl_set:Nn \l__acro_longonly_tl { <class> }`).  I think it's less effort than having to modify the `short` key as well and much easier to disable (change `\l__acro_longonly_tl` to a different string and suddenly the switch will never fire).

Comment: If you're familiar with the extra code, I can see why it would be preferrable.

Comment: This is a great solution.

If you don't want to use classes, you could also define a new property with `\acro_declare_simple_property:n { disabled }` and use it to trigger this behaviour `\acro_get_property:nnTF { #1 } { disabled } {
        \acro_long:n { #1 }
    } {
        \acro_useold:n { #1 }
    }`.

Now just add the `disabled` property to your acronym declaration, and you're good to go!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with v3.4 (and in analogy to the option and the property `first-style`) `acro` has the *option* `subsequent-style` which sets the style for all appearances after the first for all acronyms, to be set with `\acsetup{}` and initially set to `short`.  It also has the *property* with the same name which sets the same for an individual acronym (and which of course takes precedence over the option):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}[2020/12/25]% v3.4 or newer

\DeclareAcronym{aa}{
  short = a ,
  long = the letter a
}

\DeclareAcronym{bb}{
  short = b ,
  long = the letter b ,
  subsequent-style = long
}

\begin{document}

First: \texttt{aa}: \ac{aa}, \texttt{bb}:  \ac{bb} \par
Next: \texttt{aa}: \ac{aa}, \texttt{bb}:  \ac{bb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, cgnieder.  My package management is from Cygwin, and my latest update was approximately 1.5 months ago, plus/minus 0.5 months.  Its version is `Package: acro 2020/03/07 v2.11d`.  I will try your solution in my next report.

Comment: +1. I think the OP's exact use case would set both `first-style=long` and `subsequent-style=long`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use my `AFTERNOTE` above together with the `exclude-classes` option to the `printacronyms` command.  I have to include the field `class = dummy` in the acronym definition (any name for the class will do, it doesn't need to be `dummy`).

It's not elegant, but it works.  Better solutions are welcome.